# Increase width of one specific line coreplot

Tags: ios, graph, line, core-plot

I have lines going from the bottom of my *x-axis* all the way up to the graph. But I would like to make one line thicker than the other *5*.

```
majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5f;
majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
```

I have five line tick marks with *width* of *0.5*. I am just trying to make one of those specific lines thicker than the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another axis without tick marks to draw a thick line over the grid lines from another axis. Set its orthogonal coordinate to the location of the grid line you want to cover.